# Javascript onkeydown function runs and then display goes away

Tags: javascript, forms, function, onkeydown

first time on the website, anyway my problem is that when I use onkeydown and then use GetChar to check if the enter key was pressed, when operAtion runs,the results of the function only shows on the screen for about a second and then goes away, if the user uses the onclick (clicks the enter button), then this problem doesnt occur. How do I get the result of operAtion to stay on the screen when onkeydown is used. The website is sqrtcalc.comze.com if you want to see what I mean

[sqrtcalc](http://www.sqrtcalc.comze.com)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
```

```
<title>Square Root Calculator</title>

    <script language="javascript">
        function operAtion (form){
            var x = form.inputbox.value;
                if (isNaN(x)){
                    //document.write("lawl");
                    var y = "Enter a number";
                    document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                } else if (x < 0){
                    var y = "Number must be positive";
                    document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                } else if (x == ""){
                    var y = "uhm, you didnt enter anything";
                    document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
                } else {
                    var y = Math.pow(x, 1/2)
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The square root of " + x + " is " + y;
                    document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = "";
                }
        }
        function GetChar (event,form){
            var keyCode = event.keyCode;
                if (keyCode == 13){
                operAtion(form);
                }
        }
    </script>

<p></p>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" action="" method="get" style = "font-size:50px"><strong>Square Root Calculator</strong></br>
    </br>
<input type="text" name="inputbox" value = "" onkeydown = "GetChar(event,this.form);"> </br>
    </br>
<input id="button" type="button" name="button" value="     Enter      " onclick="operAtion(this.form)" >
</form>

<h1 id = "failsafe"></h1>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<h1 id = "demo"></h1>
</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
<img border="0"  src="http://counter.rapidcounter.com/counter/1353157574/a"; ALIGN="middle" HSPACE="4" VSPACE="2" style = "padding-left:1400px;">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? "Minimise bandwidth for your example, do not bore the audience"

Comment: You're clicking a button within a form, which means you're actually submitting the form. You need to disable the form submission so you don't do a full-blown server round-trip.

Comment: `</br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>`  This is crazy, and I don't believe it is even valid.  Use `<br />` instead, and don't use them for arbitrary spacing!  Use CSS margins or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code:

```
        window.onload = function(){
            document.getElementById("myform").onsubmit = function(){
                return false;
            }
        }
```

And add the id attribute `id="myform"` to the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a little:

- I removed your inline functions (inline JS isn't exactly best
  practice)
- I added an ID to your form so it could be referenced
- I added `return false;` to keep the form from submitting
- onsubmit handles both click and enter

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit = function() {
    var x = this.inputbox.value;

    if (isNaN(x)) {
        //document.write("lawl");
        var y = "Enter a number";
        document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (x < 0) {
        var y = "Number must be positive";
        document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    } else if (x == "") {
        var y = "uhm, you didnt enter anything";
        document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = y;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        var y = Math.pow(x, 1 / 2)
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The square root of " + x + " is " + y;
        document.getElementById("failsafe").innerHTML = "";
    }

    return false;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get" style="font-size:50px" id="myform"><strong>Square Root Calculator</strong><br>
    <br>
<input type="text" name="inputbox"> <br>
    <br>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="     Enter      ">
</form>

<h1 id="failsafe"></h1>

<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/hvJbk/)​

Comment: @timeshift117 It's standard practice on Stackoverflow to accept an answer if it has solved your problem. It seems both mine and hebikuzure's answer worked for you. So feel free to accept one... oh and up votes are free and show appreciation.